# Howto add custom utility / module in YUI3

Tags: module, yui3

I would like to register a custom utility / module within YUI3 that is passed one or more custom node(s) and that can be called like this (without having to instantiate it):

```
YUI().use('myCustomModule', function (Y) {
 Y.one('nodeToProcess').myCustomUtility(config);
 Y.all('manyNodes').myCustomUtility(config);
});
```

jQuery offers a similar functionality.

I know that a custom module in YUI3 is defined like this:

```
YUI.add('myCustomModule', function(Y) {
// my Code here
}, '0.1', {
requires : ['node']
});
```

But what I don't understand is how to setup my custom module, so that I can call it like described. Do I have to extend Plugin / Widget class or use Y.Namespace() to get this to work? (see http://www.slideshare.net/caridy/building-yui-3-custom-modules )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
    <script>
YUI.add('joiz', function(Y) {

    function joizMagic(context, config) {
        alert(config.name + ' says: "' + this.getContent() + '"');
    }

    // define a function that will run in the context of a
    // Node instance:
    Y.Node.addMethod("joizMagic", joizMagic);

    // extend this functionality to NodeLists:
    Y.NodeList.importMethod(Y.Node.prototype, "joizMagic");

}, '0.1.1' /* module version */, {
    requires: ['node']
});
YUI().use('joiz', function (Y)
{
    Y.all('.message').joizMagic({ name: 'Beatrice' });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="message">Hello World!</div>
    <div class="message">I'm still here!</div>
</body>
</html>
```